B4x - Implement 2FA control
I have an issue will trying to implement 2FA in my app. The goal here is simply to give me the OTP code, no issue to generate Qr Code or to scan a QR code. I tried using this example. The lib gives a secretpassword, but that does not give the same code on another 2FA app. This thus is an incorrect solution.  After some research I can have the same code as the example by using the base32 encoded password in other 2FA app but it's not a solution.
Source for my "Base32 decode" function
Sub DecodeBase32(encodedString As String) As String
    Dim Base32Alphabet As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567"
    Dim result As String = ""
    Dim paddedEncodedString As String = encodedString.Replace("=", "") 
    
    For i = 0 To paddedEncodedString.Length - 1 Step 8 
        Dim blockBits As String = ""
        For j = 0 To 7
            Dim charIndex As Int
            If i + j < paddedEncodedString.Length Then
                charIndex = Base32Alphabet.IndexOf(paddedEncodedString.CharAt(i + j))
            End If

            If charIndex <> -1 Then
                Dim paddedBinaryString As String = PadStart(Bit.ToBinaryString(charIndex), 5, "0")
                blockBits = blockBits & paddedBinaryString
            Else
                Log("BAD car")
                Return ""
            End If
        Next
        For j = 0 To 39 Step 8
            Dim byteValue As Int = Bit.ParseInt(blockBits.SubString2(j, j + 7), 2)
            result = result & Chr(byteValue) 
        Next
    Next

    Return result
End Sub

Sub PadStart(input As String, length As Int, paddingChar As String) As String
    Dim result As String = input
    Do While result.Length < length
        result = paddingChar & result
    Loop
    Return result
End Sub

I attempted 2 solutions but don't have them working:

I tried to have a base32 decode function to decode, because that seems to be a solution to have a good secretpassword at the beginning. However, everything I tested did not work (for example KU3UMWRXGVEQ decoded should result in U7FZ75I, but that wasn't returned)
I tried to use an external library but I don't know how to create a wrapper for that.


[tag:totp] has 29 watchers. Are there more tags you can add to your question, such as the language you are programming in? That way, your question will get more exposure.
